# Facebook messenger bot: enable persistent menu composer temporary

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

How to temporarily show messenger text composer to allow user input some text?

In my case, I want to allow a user to pass some item name.

The persistent menu docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/persistent-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change persistent menu specifically for any user. If you turn on your composer, it will turn on for all the users.
You can alternatively, turn the composer on by default and keep ignoring messages if not necessary.